# testing a database connection with wpf application and sqlcmd

Tags: database-connection, sqlcmd

I need to test a database connection from my wpf application, that is, a method like:

```
bool TestCon(string dbserver, string user, string password, string dbname)
{
    bool success;
    // code
    return success;
}
```

I have seen I can use sqlcmd -S dbserver -U user -P password -d dbname, but it's not clear how can I read an answer from sqlcmd so my program can say: connection successful!! or bad login!! or bad server!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you *have* to use sqlcmd?  If not, you would be much better off to use ADO.NET...

```
bool TestCon(...)
{
  try
  {
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
    {
      connection.Open();
      connection.Close();
      return true;
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i query my database using ado.net and get an output like sqlserver management studio??

Comment: @blur, this is a pretty broad question and there are any number of ways to accomplish this.  I would suggest you start by reading through the ADO.NET documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=VS.100).aspx